# SQL program to find rows from one table that are associated with ALL rows in another table

Tags: sql

I have three tables

- movies (mov_id(key), name, actor,...)
- customer (cust_id(key), name, gender,....)
- watches_movie (cust_id mov_id, movie_price,...)

I want to find out the names of all the female customers who have watched ALL the movies with a particular actor.

I am having trouble writing an SQL query for this.

Can somebody help me out?

Comment: What RDBMS?  SQL is a language, not a database.

Comment: Your data structure does not make sense.  A movie has more than one actor.

Answer (score 1):

```
   select c.cust_id, c.name, c.gender
     from customer c
     join movies m on m.actor = 'Actor'
left join watches_movie w on w.cust_id=c.cust_id and m.mov_id=w.mov_id
    where c.gender = 'Female'
 group by c.cust_id, c.name, c.gender
   having count(distinct m.mov_id) = count(distinct w.mov_id)
```

Breakdown:

1. I want to find out the names of all the female customers

   - from customer + where c.gender = 'Female'
2. ALL the movies with a particular actor

   - join movies + m.actor = 'Actor
3. who have watched `2. ALL the movies with a particular actor`. So let's find all the watches_movie records for the customer/movie combination

   - left join watches_movie on both customer/movie
4. So many record, let's break them up by customer and inspect them in groups

   - group by c.cust_id, c.name, c.gender
   - note: list as many columns from customer table as required here and in the SELECT
5. And here's where we test for this fact. If the customer has watched all the movies in (m), then there would be a (w) record for each (m) record

   - having count(distinct m.mov_id) = count(distinct w.mov_id)
   - Note: we use distinct because it's possible for a customer to watch a movie 3 times, which would count 3 times without distinct

Comment: You really should try describing what `isn't working` rather than just stating it. We can't progress because there's nothing to go on.

Answer (score 0):

This query finds all customer for whom it is true that no movie exists that they have not watched:

```
 SELECT * FROM customer WHERE gender = 'F' AND NOT EXISTS 
     (
     SELECT * FROM movies WHERE actor = 'Particular Actor' AND  mov_id NOT IN 
     (
      SELECT mov_id FROM watches_movie WHERE cust_id = customer.cust_id
     )
     );
```

Won't be too fast if there's a lot of data, but will do what you want.

BTW, you know that you have a normalization issue with the actor stored in the movie table, right?